# Is it Possible to get the Tales from the Borderlands Series on Disc?

Tags: tales-from-the-borderlands

So far, I have purchased the Game of the Year Editions for Borderlands & Borderlands 2, and am preparing to buy Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel very shortly. However, I cannot find Tales from the Borderlands, except on the Playstation Store. This poses a problem, as I have no internet access. Can somebody tell me if there's any way to get the series on disc, possibly at GameStop or on eBay? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't currently a disc-based release of Tales from the Borderlands.  However, in the past Telltale has released games on disc after the entire season is finished, so it's possible that there eventually will be a disc-based release.

[Polygon reports](http://www.polygon.com/2016/2/18/11049686/tales-from-the-borderlands-release-date-retail-disc-price) that the disc-based release will be available in late April:

> Tales from the Borderlands: A Telltale Games Series, the Telltale adventure game set in the Borderlands universe, will be released April 26 at retail in North America, publisher 2K Games announced today.
>
> The disc will include Tales from the Borderlands in its entirety, all five episodes. It will be available on PlayStation 3, PlayStation 4, Windows PC, Xbox 360 and Xbox One. The console versions will cost $29.99 each, while the PC version will go for $19.99. You can see the box art for each platform below. The collection will be released April 21 in Australia and New Zealand, and April 22 in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's not out yet.

It will be available on PlayStation 3, PlayStation 4, Xbox 360, Xbox One, and PC.

Release dates are:

- North America - April 26
- Europe - April 22
- Australia / New Zealand - April 21

Price will be $19.99 for PC, and $29.99 for all other platforms.